# jpa 2.0 with hibernate persistence query cache disabling

Tags: spring, caching, jpa

I am using the following persistence configuration with jpa2 (eclipseLink), spring 4.0.2, hibernate 4.3. Somehow the query result is always cached i.e. when I change the database in another application (e.g. direct sql) by inserting a new row, the new row is not returned here unless i restart the server (tomcat7 here). Am I missing anything here? thanks a lot!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">   

    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>soma</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.mycompany.model.MyModelClass</class>

        <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode" value="NONE" />
            <property name="org.hibernate.cacheable" value="false" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Do you see an sql select during the result call?

Comment: Good question. I did see queries being generated from hibernate as "Hibernate: select ..."

Answer (score 0):

after I added connection pooling, it all works fine now ;-)

```
<!-- pooling -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="100" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```